# Fixing Permissions on Docker

Tags: docker, permissions

I am totally novice on docker and never had an experience on creating images or what.

My question is, i want to change the permission of a directory to my current user. Certain files are currently owned by root.

However when i tried to issue:

> chown docker-user -R ./

It tells me the following:

```
changing ownership of './someFile.js': Operation not permitted
changing ownership of './otherFile.js': Operation not permitted
```

How can I change the ownership?

Thanks!

Note: Im using Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't really know where you try to do this (inside the dockerfile or just on the host). But I would recommend to use sudo to perform chown operations (inside dockerfile use `USER root` and change after it back to the preferred user)

Comment: @lorenzvth7 i really dont know the difference between "inside the dockerfile" or "just on the host". Im sorry i am really novice in this kind of things. I tried sudo but it said command not found.

Comment: @lorenzvth7, my co worker just instructed me to issue docker-compose exec --user docker-user:docker-user php55 bash.